# Ember Data "modelFor" error when serializing models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am using ember 1.13, ember-cli and ember data 1.19.1 and I am experiencing an error that is difficult to track down due to being unspecific. The error occurs  when I do the following:

```
this.get('model').forEach(function(mymodel) {
    applications.push(elavonApplication.serialize({includeId: true}));
});
```

where "elavonApplication" is an instance of a DS.Model called "elavon-application" and a snippet of the error itself is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modelFor' of undefined
ember$data$lib$system$model$$default.reopenClass.typeForRelationship @
ext.js:171ember$data$lib$system$model$$default.reopenClass._findInverseFor @     
ext.js:214ember$data$lib$system$model$$default.reopenClass.inverseFor @ 
ext.js:205Ember.Mixin.create.removeEmbeddedForeignKey @ embedded-records-mixin.js:317
Ember.Mixin.create.serializeBelongsTo @ embedded-records-mixin.js:199
```

The elavon-application inherits from a parent DS.Model called iso-application. The models are below:

```
// models/iso_application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    status: DS.belongsTo('iso-application-status'),
    statusId: DS.attr('number'),
    quickQuote: DS.belongsTo('quick-quote'),
    quickQuoteId: DS.attr('number'),
    acquirer: DS.belongsTo('acquirer'),
    acquirerId: DS.attr('number'),
    cardPresentStatus: DS.belongsTo('iso-application-status'),
    cardPresentStatusId: DS.attr('number'),
    ecommStatus: DS.belongsTo('iso-application-status'),
    ecommStatusId: DS.attr('number'),
});

// models/elavon-application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import IsoApplication from 'paya-operations/models/iso-application';

export default IsoApplication.extend({  
    principal: DS.belongsTo('iso-elavon-principal'),
    businessInfo: DS.belongsTo('iso-elavon-business-info'),
});
```

The iso-application model has several relationships including one called "status", which links to the "iso-application-status" DS.Model below:

```
// models/iso-application-status.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    isoApplications: DS.hasMany('iso-application', {inverse: 'status'}),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    colour: DS.attr('string')
});
```

The error only occurs when the relationships are present. After putting in breakpoints and stepping through the code as it runs I have found that in the "typeForRelationship" function in ext.js where Ember is throwing the error the "store" parameter is empty when the error occurs. As I stepped through it was provided for each relationship I have in my models and then when it reached the "status" relationship for it became null. I don't know why this is but it isn't to do with the data supplied to the model as all of the status ids are present in the database.

I use the ActiveModelSerializer and the EmbeddedRecordsMixin to access my server backend. I don't have a serializer for the iso-application-status model or the iso-application model. All of the the properties of iso-application are inherited by the elavon-application model so I have a serializer for that instead:

```
// serializers/elavon-application.js
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {        
        status: {embedded: 'always'},
        quickQuote: {embedded: 'always'},
        acquirer: {embedded: 'always'},
        principal: {embedded: 'always'},
        businessInfo: {embedded: 'always'},
    }
});
```

Does anyone know what I have done wrong please?

Thanks.

Comment: What response does the server provide?

Comment: You say all status IDs are present.. You've specified status as an embedded record - meaning the data should be expecting the full object, not just an ID that references the object.. Without seeing the data from the server that'd be my first guess

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I wasn't very clear but the json back from the server for the status record does contain an Object in this form {id: "6", description: "Onboarding", colour: "yellow"}.  In fact, in the Ember Inspector I am able to see the models so they've been pulled in ok.

Comment: The error occurs on the line I mention above (applications.push(mymodel.serialize({includeId: true}));) within the forEach, which is serializing the model to be added in to an array.  It occurs on the first model in the collection and as you can see from the stack trace I provided it is part of the belongsTo being serialized (Ember.Mixin.create.serializeBelongsTo).  Does this help at all?

Comment: Remove `attrs` from the iso-application-status serialiser to begin with - that's not where you specify async:true - you specify it in the model.. You given the my-model model .. What does the iso-application-status mode look like? Also, try adding this: `status: DS.belongsTo('iso-application-status', { inverse: null })`

Comment: Not sure why I put async: true in to the serializer!  I think I got confused while trying to understand how it all worked. Ok, I've removed the references to that now.  You've asked for the iso-application-status model but that's already above.  The serializer is not customized and so just uses the EmbeddedRecordsMixin defaults.  I still get the error when adding your suggested inverse: null line.

Comment: It looks like there is only `my-model` above - there is only one `DS.Model.extend` statement.. You have both serializers but only one model.. Also - what versions of ember and ember data are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I have re-written my question with the actual names of the models now rather than the ones I used to try to simplify the question (it didn't work!)  Would you mind re-reading and hopefully it will all make more sense now.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the file named `models/iso_application.js` or `models/iso-application.js`? That may be completely irrelevant but I just spent about 30 mins troubleshooting an issue trying to recreate your issue and it was because i had a typo in iso-application - and I just noticed you've called it with an _ and a -

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me with this and I'm sorry you've had a bit of trouble.  I am using iso-application.js.  I use hyphens throughout as I understand this to be the ember-cli way.

Comment: I've created a JSBin where I'm unable to replicate your issue.. I've copied as much of you scenario as I could.. Would you be able to clone this JSBin as a starting point and try and replicate your issue? http://jsbin.com/xugoqu/edit?js,console,output

Comment: It is really odd that the JSBin works as it is essentially identical to what I am doing.  I've stripped my models back down to the bare bones and I am going to gradually re-introduce each relationship except the "status" one.  If I can get them all working then I'll know they are fine and I can concentrate on getting the status one working.  Thanks for all your help and for pointing out my serializer issues; I've removed most of the serializers as a result as they were not required! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix the problem by re-installing ember-cli and ember-data. I assume something went awry during the upgrade process recently when I went from version 1.12.0 to 1.13.0 and ember-data 1.0.0-beta.17.0 to 1.0.0-beta.19.1.